# jQuery Add/Remove form fields plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am looking for a good plugin to add/remove a set of form fields in a page.

Like this one http://vipullimbachiya.com/jQuery/Plugins/MultiField/SampleMultiField.htm#example .

This plugin can do what I want but am trying to find out if there is any better option available. I have seen one excellent plugin some time back but lost the url.

Comment: define "any better option" please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dynamic-form plugin solves this problem.